# How solve this problem in android studio Build Output Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac ERROR

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I am useing android Letest Version Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
but a problem not solve plase discribe how to solve this problem

Comment: Please share the logcat

Comment: > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.

Answer (score 0):

You used **deprecated API**, to solve this problem remove **deprecated** methods from your app. The **deprecated** **API** example is below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
}
```